# Passing IDs to views, how to avoid possible manipulations?

Tags: javascript, php, security, web, laravel-5

I want to let admin user to attach users to groups, so I pass users ids with their names as array of `{id:, name:}`, and admin will be able to attach users to the edited group via html& javascript based interface in the browser.

So, what if the admin altered the array of users, and set different ids before posting the attached users to server? in such possibility, admin might be able to assign hacked ids to the server.. then un-expected users will be attached the group as a result.

Another possibility, when admin sends a hacked id for the group it self!

What is the recommended approach in such case? how often such case is handled in web-development?

Comment: You need to control your data in PHP after your ajax call. For example, test if the ID provided is numeric, or exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, you need to validate the user input.

- Is the request coming from the admin? (i.e. are they correctly authenticated?)
- Are the ids in the request real ones?
- Are they authorised to alter the details of the users whose ids are in the request?
- Are they authorised to alter the group?

etc.

Comment: So, basically, I don't have to add an encryption layer (encrypt ids) ? I can just validate ids against roles and owner..(etc) right?

Comment: Correct (although running the communication between client and server through HTTPS is always a good idea).

Comment: Thanks, I was worried about the overhead of encrypting ids.. your answer is a relief :)